# Batch command for a GDAL script

Tags: batch-file, gis, gdal, qgis

I have the following GDAL script using the OSGeo console that i have tested for one image, that I want to change now to run over every image in one folder and output to another folder?

Edit: the code I posted was a test I ran on one image to check visual quality. I was happy with the visual quality after compressing my test image. I now want to apply the script to approx. 1000 images located in one folder and output to another folder.

Edit: i am not sure why I have received a downvote for asking a question in a straightforward manner? I have checked numerous other posts on SO and reddit and have not been able to get any process to work within the QGIS OsGeo framework and would value some advice.

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES "D:\split outputs\raster_compression test\EQ_GLNG_Photo_2018_MGA550.tif" "D:\split outputs\raster_compression test\0001_JPEG.tif" -scale -ot Byte
```

Comment: I imagine something like `for %%A in ("D:\split outputs\raster_compression test\*.tif") do ECHO gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=JPEG -co PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR -co TILED=YES "%%~fA" "D:\split outputs\raster_compression test\%%~nA.tif" -scale -ot Byte` (it just prints the commands but doesn't execute them unless you remove the `ECHO`). If you want to name them like `0001_JPEG.tif` etc, you would also need to implement a counter.

Answer (score 0):

In the QGIS python console something like the following should work

This expects your input and output folders to exist, and it expects that the input folder contains all tif files as a child (not in sub folders)

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

input_folder = 'path_to_input'
output_folder = 'path_to_output'
options = gdal.TranslateOptions(
    outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte, 
    scaleParams=[''], 
    creationOptions=['COMPRESS=JPEG', 'PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR', 'TILED=YES']
)

for entry in os.listdir(input_folder):
    if entry.endswith('.tif'):
        gdal.Translate(
            os.path.join(output_folder, entry),
            os.path.join(input_folder, entry),
            options=options
        )
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir, I will try this now.